# Regarding Spring WS Security using XWSS

Tags: spring-security, spring-ws

I am implementing a Spring WS using NetBeans and JDK1.6. I want to implement Spring WS Security framework using XWSS. It requires a securityPolicy.xml file but when I deploy the application an try hitting the WSDL URL, it gives me below exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor#2': Cannot create inner bean 'wsSecurityInterceptor' of type [org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wsSecurityInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'xwss:SecurityConfiguration'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor#2': Cannot create inner bean 'wsSecurityInterceptor' of type [org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wsSecurityInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'xwss:SecurityConfiguration'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:616)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:400)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.AbstractEndpointMapping.initInterceptors(AbstractEndpointMapping.java:101)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.AbstractEndpointMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractEndpointMapping.java:92)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.AbstractAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.java:60)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:117)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1448)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wsSecurityInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'xwss:SecurityConfiguration'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
        ... 51 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'xwss:SecurityConfiguration'.
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.XWSSProcessor2_0Impl.<init>(XWSSProcessor2_0Impl.java:72)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.XWSSProcessorFactory2_0Impl.createProcessorForSecurityConfiguration(XWSSProcessorFactory2_0Impl.java:52)
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(XwsSecurityInterceptor.java:112)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'xwss:SecurityConfiguration'.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:124)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.config.SecurityConfigurationXmlReader.parseXmlStream(SecurityConfigurationXmlReader.java:249)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.config.SecurityConfigurationXmlReader.parseXmlStream(SecurityConfigurationXmlReader.java:224)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.config.SecurityConfigurationXmlReader.createDeclarativeConfiguration(SecurityConfigurationXmlReader.java:282)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.XWSSProcessor2_0Impl.<init>(XWSSProcessor2_0Impl.java:66)
        ... 58 more
```

I have checked many online resources and everywhere its written that SecurityConfiguration is the root element of the securityPolicy.xml file if the WS is not a JAX-RPC based WS. Now I have no idea why this exception is occuring. Anyone having any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.

**My solution:**
Don't let spring scan the securityPolicy.xml as a bean.

```
securityPolicy.xml:
<xwss:SecurityConfiguration xmlns:xwss="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/xwss/config">
    <xwss:RequireUsernameToken passwordDigestRequired="false" nonceRequired="false"/>
</xwss:SecurityConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add xmlns:xwss="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/xwss/config" ?

Posting your SecurityPolicy.xml would help!